Filter some queries with mariadb's replication
I want to make a safe master/slave replication, without drop/truncate. Which can help if we made mistake about drop/truncate table, or in case of hack/injection.
I searched for a replication restriction:

As the replication user on the slave is the super user, we cannot change privileges about it
It's binary file, we can't edit them
There is no option as "Prevent drop table"
The only filter were about filter table/database that are managed by the replication. I already changed them, and it's not what I'm looking for.
I'm also using MASTER_DELAY that can help if we made the mistake by ourself.

Is that possible? How can I do it?

@ErgestBasha safe in term of accidentally remove everything

The binlogfilter module in MariaDB MaxScale allows you to exclude or rewrite events in the replication stream. With it, you could use a exclude=/DROP TABLE/ filter to discard drop table commands.
Here's a simple MaxScale configuration that would accept replication on port 3306 and forward it to the db1 server. If a DROP TABLE SQL command would be replicated, it would be removed from the replication stream.
[maxscale]
threads=auto

[db1]
type=server
address=...
port=...

[Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=db1
user=...
password=...

[BinlogFilter]
type=filter
module=binlogfilter
# This is a PCRE2 regular expression
exclude=/(?i)DROP TABLE/

[Service]
type=service
router=readconnrouter
router_options=master
cluster=Monitor
user=...
password=...

[Listener]
type=listener
service=Service
protocol=mariadbclient
port=3306


Thanks for your answer, I'll try it soon. Here you show example for one command. To add another one, I have to change the regex, or can I simply add new [BinlogFilter] part?

If the commands are relatively simple, extending the regex would be simpler than adding another filter.

And so, it would like /(?i)DROP TABLE|OTHERCMD/ ?

Yes, it's a standard PCRE2 regular expression so that should do it: https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html Note that some care must be taken when using regular expressions as that regex would match something like INSERT INTO event_log VALUES (1, 'DROP TABLE t1'); Making sure that the expression is anchored to the start of the statement using ^ should avoid this problem but things like comments and such may still cause problems.
